# How to cite a herbarium specimen

Tags: botany, literature

How do I cite a herbarium specimen that I have used to prepare a botanical description? Do I use the collector's name and number or the herbarium code and accession number? What if there is no record of the collector's name or number?

Comment: In general, the "how to cite", depends on the journal you publish. Check on their website (hot to submit) or check common journal used in your field, and copy the style used in articles.